# From $\|g\|_2 =1$ to $\|g\|_\infty^2 \ge \dim V$ on a subspace of $C[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

> Let $V$ be a finite dimensional subspace of $C[0,1]$. Prove that there exists $g \in V$ such that $\|g\|_2 =1$, $\|g\|_\infty^2 \ge \dim V$

In this problem we use the notation
$$\|f\|_2 = \left(\int_0^1 f^2\right)^{1/2}$$
$$\|f\|_\infty = \max_{[0,1]} f$$

**My attempt**

For the n-dimensional situation.
Suppose that $f_i=\chi_{[\frac{i-1}{n}, \frac{i}{n}]}$ are the characteristic functions of intervals.

Then the condition is equivalent to that for $f=\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i f_i$ 
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i^2 = n^2$$

Thus $$\|f\|_\infty^2 = \max \lambda_i^2 \geqslant n$$The inequality holds.

But I got stuck on analyzing the general situation. Could you please give me some hints? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer. The core idea is to find an orthogonal basis to reduce complexity.

**Proof**

Choose the orthogonal basis $f_1,f_2,\cdots,f_n$ such that
$$
\int_0^1f_if_j=\delta_{ij} \quad \forall\, 1\le i \le j\le n
$$
Thus for $f=\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i f_i$
$$
\int_0^1 f^2 = \int_0^1 \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i^2 f_i^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i^2 
$$
which implies that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i^2 = 1 \tag{1}
$$

In addition, since
$$
\int_0^1 \sum_{i=1}^n f_i^2 = n
$$
we can choose $x_0 \in [0,1]$ such that
$$
 \sum_{i=1}^n f_i^2(x_0) \ge n \tag{2}
$$

Note that
$$
 \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i f_i(x_0)\right)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i^2 \cdot \sum_{i=1}^n f_i^2(x_0) 
$$
holds if we choose appropriate $\lambda_i $.

Then via $(1)$ and $(2)$ we arrive at the conclusion.